# How could I shuffle a list to this rule?

Tags: python, arrays, algorithm, shuffle

I am trying to make an algorithm to shuffle a list and then make a new list of all the combinations according to this rule:

You are only allowed to swap one pair. For example:

```
array = [1, 2, 3]
[3, 2, 1]        #number at index 0 switched with number at index 2
```

Any thoughts on how to write it?

**Edit:** 
Saschas code worked well. I wrote this code before asking the question:

```
sols = []
for i in range(len(a)):
    for j in range(len(a)):
        a[i] = a[j]
        a[j] = a[i]
        sols_perm.append(a)
```

I was aware that I would get some identical elements in the list because of unordered pairs but it just created a list full of identical elements. Any thoughts why?

Comment: Your swapping is wrong. You would need a temporary-variable (a[i] changed before used to set a[j]). The code in my approach is working different (python-style swap) ! Next time add the code directly!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
sols = []
for i in range(len(array)):
    for j in range(i+1, len(array)):    # symmetry-reduction -> ordered pairs
        sol = array[:]                  # copy list
        sol[i], sol[j] = sol[j], sol[i] # swap
        sols.append(sol)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the function below:

```
def swap(inlist):
    n = len(inlist)
    res = [x for x in inlist]
    for i in range(n):
        for j in range(i+1, n):
            tmp = res[i]
            res[i] = res[j]
            res[j] = tmp
    return res
```